# wso2 ESB JMS Listener

Tags: wso2-esb

i while trying to listen the message from JMS Queue with wso2 esb according to http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/samples/transport_samples.html/sample 250 I am getting an exception as

XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location:
<TryitProxyError h:status='messageContext error' xmlns:h='http://wso2.org/ns/TryitProxy'>org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information from the jms:/JmsListener?transport.jms.DestinationType=queue&transport.jms.ContentTypeProperty=contentType&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType=queue&transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory URL.</TryitProxyError> ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^

wso2.org wso2.org

1 day ago

hi while trying to listen the message from JMS Queue with wso2 esb according to http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/samples/transport_samples.html/sample 250 I am getting an exception as

XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location:
<TryitProxyError h:status='messageContext error' xmlns:h='http://wso2.org/ns/TryitProxy'>org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information from the jms:/JmsListener?transport.jms.DestinationType=queue&transport.jms.ContentTypeProperty=contentType&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType=queue&transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory URL.</TryitProxyError> ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^

wso2.org wso2.org

1 day ago

Comment: Are you trying the sample exactly in the documentation? or do you have any customization in your proxy?

Comment: Seems like you are using "try it" utility..Not sure it will work for JMS transports...Try the sample axis2 client to execute the service or use SOAPUI to send requests

Comment: yes I am using try it utility in wso2 but it doesnt work even in SOAPUI

Comment: Did you enable the jms transport sender+listener in both servers(esb+axis2server)?

Comment: yes I did enabled the JMS transport

Comment: Have you started the activemq server before start ESB ?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the following location for JMS samples [1], make sure that you have opened up the JMS sende ,receiver transport services defined at the axis2.xml, and also you need to make sure that all the required JMS broker libraries are included in the ESB_HOME/repository/components/lib

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB403/Sample+251+Switching+from+HTTP%28S%29+to+JMS

cheers
Dushan